# Coding segmented regression terms in a two part (hurdle) regression model

Tags: r, interaction, logistic-regression

I am using a two-part or hurdle model to model the probability of flight given a set of covariates (hurdle part) and another set of coavriates to model the negative binomial part of the model.

First I iteratively searched for the best predictors to explain the presence or absence of zeros in the data. One continuous predictor and one dichotomous predictor were chosen based on AIC criteria. I then explored the use of a segmented term for the continuous predictor. One breakpoint in the continuous covariate markedly improved the fit.

Here is the output from the segmented package

```
Estimated Break-Point(s):
   Est. St.Err 
 3.849  1.368 

t value for the gap-variable(s) V:  0 

Meaningful coefficients of the linear terms:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)     -0.2744     0.3556  -0.772   0.4403  
approach_km     -0.4526     0.2184  -2.072   0.0383 *
sea2             0.3627     0.2280   1.591   0.1117  
U1.approach_km   0.4549     0.2188   2.079       NA
```

the slope for the U1.approach_km coefficient is the difference between its coefficient and the approach_km coefficient, essentially zero. So at distances greater than the breakpoint, approach_km no longer predicts presence or absence.

I figured out a way to code in these variables in order to add them to the hurdle model, which is essential just a basic glm form but with two sets (of possible different) coavriates separated by a | symbol.

```
manual <- glm(occur ~ approach_km + I(pmax(approach_km-3.849,0)) + sea, data=land11, family=binomial)
summary(manual)

Coefficients:
                                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                     -0.27441    0.29347  -0.935    0.350    
approach_km                     -0.45261    0.09993  -4.529 5.92e-06 ***
I(pmax(approach_km - 3.849, 0))  0.45486    0.10723   4.242 2.22e-05 ***
sea2                             0.36271    0.22803   1.591    0.112
```

This results in the same coefficient estimates but different Std. errors. It also results in the same residual deviance (both 508.36) and the same AIC score 516.36 although the degrees of freedom are not the same (one less for the segmented object).

Any thoughts on how to get the Std. errors to coincide or does this not matter when entering this formula into the hurdle package